Fullcalendar refetchEvents doesn't always re-render ui with updated data
I have a problem with the calendar UI not getting refreshed upon event edit/delete. I have a custom modal which lets me edit/delete the event and upon save, data is updated to the db and there is a callback to the calendar.refetchEvents() method. The events are fetched through ajax call i.e. events (as a function). I see that the data is updated in the db and the ajax request returns the updated data,
but the problem is calendar Ui is not refreshed always. It works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't.
By this I mean the UI shows the updated data sometimes and I have to close fullcalendar view (modal in my case) and reopen again for changes to be visible. Pasting my code below. It's the same code mentioned in the docs.
let initCalendar = function () {
            calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarElement, {
                initialView: 'timeGridDay',
                headerToolbar: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'timeGridDay,timeGridWeek,dayGridMonth'
                },
                themeSystem: 'standard',
                allDaySlot: false,
                contentHeight: 'auto',
                weekends: true,
                editable: false,
                defaultTimedEventDuration: '00:15:00',
                slotEventOverlap: false,
                eventMinHeight: 30,
                buttonText: {
                    today: 'Today',
                    day: 'Daily',
                    week: 'Weekly',
                    month: 'Monthly'
                },
                events: function (fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        data: JSON.stringify({
                            startDate: fetchInfo.startStr,
                            endDate: fetchInfo.endStr,
                            id: id
                        }),
                        url: dataUrl,
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data && data.$values) {
                                let events = [];
                                $(data.$values).each(function (index, value) {
                                    let endDate = new Date(value.EndDate);
                                    let startDate = new Date(value.NewsDate);
                                    let trueEndDate = endDate.getTime();
                                    endDate = Math.floor((endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / 60000) > 15 ? endDate : null
                                    events.push({
                                        start: new Date(value.NewsDate),
                                        end: endDate,
                                        title: value.Title,
                                        trueTitle: value.Title,
                                        titleEncoded: value.TitleEncoded,
                                        trueEnd: trueEndDate,
                                        patientId: value.PatientID,
                                        patientNewsId: value.PatientNewsID,
                                        description: value.Description,
                                        outcome: value.OutCome,
                                        fullName: value.FullName,
                                        fullNameEncoded: value.FullNameEncoded,
                                        eventType: value.EventType,
                                        newsType: value.NewsType,
                                        inviteeListEncoded: value.InviteeListEncoded,
                                        inviteeListEncodedShortened: value.InviteeListEncodedShortened,
                                        createdByEncoded: value.CreatedByEncoded,
                                        viewMode: value.ViewMode,
                                        canBeDeleted: value.CanBeDeleted,
                                        canBeEdited: value.CanBeEdited,
                                        durationValue: value.Duration,
                                        display: "block",
                                    });
                                });
                                successCallback(events);
                            }
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            failureCallback()
                        }
                    });
                },
                eventContent: function (info) {
                    let eventHtml = getEventHtml(info);
                    return { html: eventHtml }
                },
                eventDidMount: function (info) {
                    //Set title attribute
                 let extendedProps = info.event.extendedProps;
                 let element = info.el;
                 let title = extendedProps.fullName + "\n" + extendedProps.newsType + ': ' + extendedProps.trueTitle + "\n" + "Outcome: " + extendedProps.outcome + "\n";
                 let hasInvitees = extendedProps.inviteeListEncoded ? true : false;
                 if (hasInvitees) {
                    title += "Invitees: " + extendedProps.inviteeListEncoded;
                 }
                info.el.title = title;

                  //Determine color
                  if (extendedProps.outcome != null) {
                    let eventColorCode = getEventColorCode(extendedProps.outcome);
                     $(element).css('background-color', eventColorCode).css("border-color", eventColorCode);
                  }

               //Hide overflown text for timeGridWeek just in case
                 if (info.view.type == "timeGridWeek") {
                    $(element).css("overflow", "hidden");
                  }
                },
                eventClick: function (info) {
                    //Custom method call
                },
                windowResize: function (arg) {
                    this.updateSize();
                }
            });
            calendar.render();
        };


let getEventHtml = function (info) {
    let innerText;
    let extendedProps = info.event.extendedProps;
    let startMoment = moment(info.event.start);
    let endMoment = moment(info.event.extendedProps.trueEnd);
    let timeText = startMoment.format("h:mm") + " - " + endMoment.format("h:mm") + " - " + info.event.extendedProps.trueTitle;

    if (extendedProps.viewMode == "Patient") {
        innerText = 'Created By: ' + extendedProps.createdByEncoded + ' ' + extendedProps.newsType + ': ' + extendedProps.titleEncoded;
    } else {
        innerText = 'Patient: ' + extendedProps.fullNameEncoded + ' ' + extendedProps.newsType + ': ' + extendedProps.titleEncoded;
    }

    let titleDiv = document.createElement("div");
    titleDiv.className = "bold-text";
    titleDiv.textContent = timeText;

    let infoDiv = document.createElement("div");
    infoDiv.textContent = htmlDecode(innerText);

    return `${titleDiv.outerHTML} ${infoDiv.outerHTML}`;
};


The success callback on edit/delete is a function which calls calendar.refetchEvents() . Ive tried
calendar.render() instead, but that too doesn't refresh the UI with updated data. Can anyone please suggest what I'm doing wrong?
The breakpoint is in the line successCallback(events);
The below data is from the events object. Initially the outcome property is "Partially Complete"

And my calendar UI looks like this:
.
The said event is highlighted.
Now I edit my event and change the outcome to "Not Complete" The calendar.refetchEvents() gets triggered and this is the updated event data from the line successCallback(events); after the ajax call.

As you can see the outcome has changed to "Not Complete".
But the UI is not refreshed after editing the event as you can see from the image here
.
Now when I close and re-open the calendar, the UI is updated - i.e. the event colour has changed , check this:
.
I hope this is helpful.

Can you confirm that in the cases where it doesn't seem to update, that successCallback(events); is actually called in that case, and that events contains some new / different data than what is already on the calendar? Unless there is some console / network error preventing the response from coming back properly, which you haven't mentioned, then I can only assume that you didn't actually give the calendar any new data for some reason. Please do some more detailed debugging and report back.

@ADyson Thanks for the tips. The events object is updated with new data and I've included screenshots for the same in the original post.

Thanks for the update. The main missing piece of the jigsaw now is the code for your getEventHtml function. Please show us that too.

@ADyson Pasted the function getEventHtml in the original post
